# String Permutations - case and order

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

## Challenge

For any string that is composed of alphabetical characters of any case, make a function that returns a list of all of it's variations, order and case-wise empty strings returns empty list.

## Test Cases

```
"" -> []
"a" -> ['a', 'A']
"ab" -> ['ab', 'Ab', 'aB', 'AB', 'ba', 'Ba', 'bA', 'BA']
"abc" -> ['abc', 'Abc', 'aBc', 'ABc', 'abC', 'AbC', 'aBC', 'ABC', 'bac', 'baC', 'bAc', 'bAC', 'Bac', 'BaC', 'BAc', 'BAC', 'CBa', 'CBA', 'cba', 'cbA', 'cBa', 'cBA', 'Cba', 'CbA', 'caB', 'cAb', 'cAB', 'cab', 'CaB', 'CAb', 'CAB', 'Cab', 'Acb', 'AcB', 'acb', 'acB', 'aCb', 'aCB', 'ACb', 'ACB', 'Bca', 'BcA', 'bca', 'bcA', 'bCa', 'bCA', 'BCa', 'BCA']
'aa' -> ['aa', 'Aa', 'aA', 'AA']  (for duplicate letters extra, duplicate permutations are allowed if necessary)
```

As the permutations rack up quickly **you only need to handle up to 4 ASCII letter chars.**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Why is this getting reopen votes? It's an exact dupe...

Comment: This uses place variation too

Comment: A couple questions. What should the input 'aa' give? Also, for the output format, since each permutation is of known length, do we need delimiters between all of them?

Comment: This seems like a combination of two problems, permutations and case-variants lol

Comment: I still don’t understand why people want this closed.

Comment: @dylnan I will let the answerer decide that, but  aa, aA, Aa, and AA are required

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 89 bytes

```python
lambda s:map(list,map(permutations,product(*zip(s.swapcase(),s))))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYoxDsIwDEV3TpEtblUxMCKxcAukLqZNhKUktmJXQC8fghB/el/vydseXE4tXuaWMN9XdHrOKJBIbfqChJo3QyMuOknldVsMxp0E9KhPlAU1wDDp0HeIlbMjC9WYkzrKwtXGJpWKQQSPV9@r3/Vz8X/uan/dumsf)

Doesn't work in Python 3. Swap case idea from HyperNeutrino.

Comment: You can golf this a tad with replacing "list" with "set".  Uglier output, but it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
żŒsp/Œ!€Ẏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//xbzFknNwL8WSIeKCrOG6jv/Dh1n//yJhYiI)

## Explanation

```
żŒsp/Œ!€Ẏ  Main Link
ż          zip each character with
 Œs        its case swapped
   p/      reduce over cartesian product
       €   for each sublist
     Œ!    find all permutations
        Ẏ  flatten by one layer
```

Comment: Lol I always get beat by a lot on my 12+ byte answers. Although if you're not doing ŒṘ or removing duplicates I might take mine out...

Comment: @dylnan I personally think that's unecessary. OP didn't specify so just leave it out unless OP specifies :P

Comment: Updated! @dylnan

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
Œu,ŒlZŒpŒ!€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//xZJ1LMWSbFrFknDFkiHigqz///8iYWIi)

**16** **bytes** if we need formatting and no repeated permutations.

```
Œu,ŒlZŒpŒ!€;/QŒṘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//xZJ1LMWSbFrFknDFkiHigqw7L1HFkuG5mP///yJhYiI)

This is assuming (a) we need delimiters between the permutations (achieved by `ŒṘ` at the end) and (b) the input `'aa'`-->`['AA','Aa','aA','aa']` and doesn't count the two 'a's as unique, which would give the same answer but each permutation would appear twice.

**Explanation**

```
Œu,ŒlZŒpŒ!€;/QŒṘ   Main link
Œu                 Upper case. 'aB'->'AB'
   Œl              Lower case. 'aB'->'ab'
  ,                Pair dyad. -> [['A','B'],['a','b']]
     Z             Zip the columns. -> [['A','a'],['B','b']]
      Œp           Cartesian product of the elements in the outermost list. -> [['A','B'],['A','b'],['a','B'],['a','b']]
        Œ!€        The permutations applied at €ach element in the list. -> [[['A','B'],['B','A']],[['A','b'],...
                   The rest is deleting duplicates and formatting.
           ;/      Concatenates the lists of permutations. In Essentially flattens the list by one level.
             Q     Remove repeated elements
              ŒṘ   Print in Python's string format
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 169 bytes

I/O format: arrays of characters.

```js
a=>(r=[],P=(a,m=[])=>a.map((_,i)=>P(b=[...a],[...m,...b.splice(i,1)]))>[]||(g=i=>i>>m.length||g(-~i,r.push(m.map((c,j)=>c[`to${i>>j&1?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`]()))))())(a)&&r
```

Not the right tool for the job... Still, there's probably a golfier way.

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>(r=[],P=(a,m=[])=>a.map((_,i)=>P(b=[...a],[...m,...b.splice(i,1)]))>[]||(g=i=>i>>m.length||g(-~i,r.push(m.map((c,j)=>c[`to${i>>j&1?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`]()))))())(a)&&r

f([...'abc']).forEach(a => console.log(a.join('')))
```